# copy file to windows system from centos using bitvise

Tags: bitvise

I ssh into centos server using user **"centos"** and there is a file **/usr/share/nginx/sitename/file.sql**, which is owned by root or some other user i don't know so i can not access file.sql directly, however if i do using sudo privilege then it is accessible

now how can i copy **file.sql using bitvise terminal when logged in via user "centos"**

i tried using **scp root@localhost:/usr/share/nginx/sitename/file.sql c:/** which gave following erro

**Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).**

Comment: Does the `scp` app actually come from Bitvise? It looks more like an OpenSSH tool – Bitvise doesn't even provide a CLI scp client.

Comment: i meant bitvise terminal console, it may be OpenSSH

Comment: Does `sudo` on the remote server generally require a password?